# Unusual time format PHP (TZ,H,M,S)

Tags: php, string, datetime

I'm being given data where time (duration) fields are given in an unusual format. I think a timezone is also given, but I'm not sure why.
An example is the following string:

```
PT3165H52M12S
```

How could I extract the hours, minutes, and seconds as integers in PHP?
So far I've tried using regex but I admittedly failed.

Is there perhaps a PHP function that could help with this that I'm unaware of?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: i think you could use str.split() in some form not exactly sure tho

Comment: That's an [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Not sure I would call it unusual. The PHP DateTime class probably handles it natively.

Comment: Oooh it's a *Duration* string **not** a time - I need to read the question more carefully I think :)

Comment: This is also the exact format that `DateInterval` accepts.

Comment: Not sure how the `TZ` from the title relates to the rest of the question though...

Comment: @jeroen - I suspect it was the OP just misinterpreting the string and reading it as a weird timestamp ... I made the same mistake initially *\*whistles innocently\**

Comment: @jeroen My bad, I was reading it as PT for "Pacific Time"... which is partly why I was so confused. Probably a very bad assumption on my part. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: @user2228716 That hadn't even occured to me :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) notation.

You can translate it to `DateInterval` object simply with:

```
$i = new DateInterval('PT3165H52M12S');
print_r($i);
```

After that you can directly access [**properties**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props) of `$i` as they are **public**.

```
echo $i->h;  // shows you `3165` (hours)
echo $i->i;  // shows you `52` (mins)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much for the help! Sorry if it was blindingly obvious... will accept your answer when it allows me to

Answer (score 2):

**The format**

You did not provided a date but a period on the ISO 8601 format. At the beginning of your string the "P" is for "period", "T" for the time, ect.

There is plenty of documentation about it, like this article on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

**Parse this period**

You can parse this period with instanciate a new `DateInterval` object like that:

`var_dump(new \DateInterval("PT3165H52M12S"))`

Will result to:

`object(DateInterval)#1 (16) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(3165)
  ["i"]=>
  int(52)
  ["s"]=>
  int(12)
  ["f"]=>
  float(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the naive regex approach for this would be pretty trivial if all the examples have hour, minute, and second sections as shown:

```
/PT(\d+)H(\d+)M(\d+)S/
```

Each `(\d+)` means "match 1 or more digits, and capture the result into a variable for later use", and everything else is just matching the literal characters.

Secondly, as pointed out in comments this is an ISO 8601 standard representation of a time interval, duration, or period, which breaks down like this:

- "P" for "Period" (to clarify that this is not an absolute date)
- "T" for "Time" (necessary because "M" can mean either Month or Minute, depending where it appears)
- "3165H" for 316 Hours (there's no restriction on hours being less than 24)
- "52M" for 52 Minutes
- "12S" for 12 Seconds

Since this is a standard, it is accepted as the default input for [the `DateInterval` class](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), so you can simply write:

```
$foo = new \DateInterval('PT3165H52M12S');
```

You can then use [the properties and methods of that class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to access the information of the interval, convert it to a format of your choice, or add/subtract it from an absolute date-time.

Comment: Another really great answer, thanks very much for the help